# Why can't I connect to Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have purchase new laptop from Dell with ubuntu 12.04 preinstalled. while connecting to Ubuntu One following occurs and I am not able to sync with Ubuntu One.

```
WebClientErr u'Error downloading https://one.ubuntu.com/api/account/ - server replied:Not      
Found' u'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n<html>
<head>\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>
Not Found</h1>\n<p>The requested URL /api/account/ was not found on this server.
</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at one.ubuntu.com Port 443
</address>\n</body></html>\n'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ubuntu One cloud services have been discontinued.  [Here's the announcement from Canonical](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/) just about one year ago.

> Today we are announcing plans to shut down the Ubuntu One file
>   services.  This is a tough decision, particularly when our users rely
>   so heavily on the functionality that Ubuntu One provides.  However,
>   like any company, we want to focus our efforts on our most important
>   strategic initiatives and ensure we are not spread too thin.

Comment: Feeling bad about news but hoping one day  they may start the service again.....